# How do I know time that Sqoop tranferred data between Hadoop and NoSQL?

Tags: hadoop, cron, couchbase, sqoop

I'm a newbie with Hadoop. I need to import data from Couchbase to HDFS. It's already accomplished. But How can I know that the data transferring is completed so that I can run a Job (MapReduce) with that data sequentially?

Thanks you so much.